# How can I use Splash Screens API with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, splash-screen

I want to use [Splash Screens API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen) in my app and I want to load data from the server in `Splash Screen` but what can I do if the connection failed? Should go to the next activity or keep the user in `Splash Screen` with an error message or something else?

What is a good approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: Don't show a splash screen at all and only use the default animations from the android OS. Show a placeholder UI in your normal activity as long as the data is loading or show cachec content.

Comment: this is entirely based on opinion and has to do with UX more than development, it's impossible for us to say here what you should do in your app when something doesn't work like it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get data from API then put it to `splash screen`. But while the connection is lost or User start app as offline then you should have another designed splash screen which start activity with message to `"on the internet connection"` or any `Warning` or `Error` Message.

Or else you can put any button of text view that suggest user to on their internet connection.